# How to store a video link in a string and decode it again in JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm saving a long string in a database which also contains embedded videos. For example when I store something like `<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY width="900" height="515"></iframe>"` in my string and read it to show it in my HTML page it's shown as a string. How can I decode it so it gets embedded?

Comment: How are you adding it to the DOM? Sounds like you can just store the url and create an iframe, set the src etc with JS.

Comment: Just by ```let string += "iframe ..."```. Yeah, thought about that, too. Was hoping there would be an even simpler solution though.

Comment: You can use `innerHTML` but that would make me a bit uncomfortable. Creating the iframe is only a few lines of code.

Comment: `document.getElementById('tag-id').innerHTML = "<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY width="900" height="515"></iframe>"` Do you add it to the DOM in this way?

Comment: @MidnightForm - storing only the URL is the simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be encoding/decoding just the url and not the iFrame, since the iFrame is consistent across all links.

```
iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.width = 900;
iframe.height = 515;
iframe.src = "INSERT URL STRING HERE";
document.querySelector("body").appendChild(iframe);
```

This will create an iFrame using the url string in vanilla javascript, and adds the iFrame as a child to the body tag.

And if you are wondering on how to encode/decode strings, try using CryptoJS.
It has methods such as `CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(string, password)` and `CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(string, password)` in which the string is what you want to encode/decode and the password is a "key" that you need to decrypt the encrypted key correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
let container = document.createElement('div');
container.innerHTML = yourStringFromDB;

// Do whatever you want with it
```